# iOS update checklist

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, bundle

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on what exactly we need to do when creating updated versions of apps. I can find documentation on iTunesConnect, but not Xcode.

I know this much:

1. Update "Bundle version" in MyApp-Info.plist
2. Update "Bundle versions string, short" in MyApp-Info.plist

Is there anything else that I'm missing?